# не могу запустить сервер в vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, framework

Запускаю npm run serve и вместо локального хоста ошибка

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall open
npm ERR! path 
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
```

Comment: Зайдите в файл package.json и посмотрите, какие скрипты доступны. Потом из этой же папки, где лежит package.json, запускайте этот скрипт